# Slide out div problems

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a slide out div that I got to remain open when in desktop view but I want it to be closed and able to slide out once in responsive view. I have tried media queries but that does not help much, the div ends up not sliding out when responsive but works perfectly normal on desktop view. Any thoughts?

```
.slide-out-div {
    font-family:Arial;
    line-height:50%;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: rgba(67, 67, 67, 0.88);
    padding: 9px 0;
    margin-bottom: 10px;    
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    width: 221px;
    height:410px;
    left:0;
    top: 106px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 4px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    text-align:left;
      }     

      fieldset{
    margin: 0 0;
    padding: 0.35em 0.625em 0.75em;
    }
    legend{padding:2px 5px;}    
    form div.col{clear:none;}form div.first{clear:both;}
    form div{overflow:hidden;}

    input[type="text"], input[type="password"], textarea, .field, .area, select{
        border:1px solid #aaa;
        padding:5px;
        background:#fff;
        line-height:1em;
        margin:0;
    }

@media only screen and (max-width: 1350px) {
    .slide-out-div {
        left:-216px !important;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1350px) {
    .slide-out-div {
        left:-216px !important;
    }
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 660px) {
    .slide-out-div {
        left:-216px !important;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 660px) {
    .slide-out-div {
        left:-216px !important;
    }
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .slide-out-div {
        left:-216px !important;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    .slide-out-div {
        left:-216px !important;
    }
}
```

That's what the css looks like.

Comment: create fiddle link

Comment: provide your html code also.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/crboo6wc/ thats with the media queries